# Choose JsonView to serialize HttpResponse at runtime

Tags: json, spring, jackson, resteasy, json-view

We have a spring backed resteasy REST API implementation using Jackson.

I want to decide at runtime (inside my resource class) which JsonView should be used to serialize the HttpResponse.

```java
@Path("/foos")
public FooResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    HttpResponse<FooRepresentation> getById(@PathParam("id") @NotNull String id);
}

public class FooRepresentation {
    @JsonView(Views.Short.class)
    private String name;

    private String description;
}

publi class FooResourceImpl {
    public HttpResponse<FooRepresentation> getById(String id) {
        Foo foo = ...;
        // How to decide here to use e.g. the Views.Short.class view?
        return foo;
    }
}
```

I'm experimenting with a custom serializer but it seems as if the view can't be configured after an object mapper has been set up. What approach could be feasible to do that?